# Automatic Language detection from Images for OCR character Extraction

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, tensorflow, python-tesseract

I am building a software using python in which the image is uploaded.The software will extract the text using tesseract ocr.

But I want my software to detect the languages in the images automatically and extract the detected text.

Please suggest me some ways to do that,I am ready to do Machine Learning also but i can't determine a perfect pipeline for the process.

Thanks In-advance.

Answer (score 3):

The process is complicated, what you need to do is

1. Extract text from image in lang=eng
2. Pass that text to langdetect it is google automatic language detection library
3. Again use that language in tesseract to extract text accurately

Or

you can use switch case with every language and pass sample text to langdetect to get probability which language is correct.

```
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 
'<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'
# Include the above line, if you don't have tesseract executable in your path

# Example tesseract_cmd: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test-european.jpg'), lang='eng'))

sample_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('image.jpg'), lang='eng')

from langdetect import detect_langs detect_langs(sample_text)
```

Comment: The switch case is better because my images will be in different languages.

Comment: actually i can't as i am a new user, stack exchange doesnt let me do that

Comment: I tried this. But this way not worked for Chinese,Arabic and Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract has script detection within "OSD", but not language Detection , you cannot detect language automatically you have to specify language.

Comment: If it can't auto-detect language, Is there any other workflows for tesseract for detecting language in the image using machine learning and then returning the detected language type to tesseract for ocr extraction?

Comment: @CyborgSuraj look into Tika. Specifically TikaOCR: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaOCR